# I need to add button in showcase view 'GOT IT'

Tags: android

I need to add button in showcase view 'GOT IT'. How to show button 'GOT IT'  here?

```
public voidshowcase() {
    new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
        .setTarget(accident)

        .setDismissText("GOT IT")
        .setDismissTextColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"))
        .setShapePadding(140)
        .setContentText("Touch the yellow fab below to see more services")
        .setDelay(withDelay) 
// optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
       .singleUse(SHOWCASE_ID) // provide a unique ID used to ensure it is only shown once
        .show();
}
```

Comment: Are you taking about showCaseView library?

Comment: Always mention the name and the link of the library you're using.

Comment: Material showcase view library

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
  private ShowcaseView showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTarget(new ViewTarget(diagnostics))
                    .setOnClickListener(counterClick)
                    .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme)
                    .build();



            showcaseView.setButtonText(getString(R.string.next));
            showcaseView.forceTextPosition(ShowcaseView.BELOW_SHOWCASE);
            showcaseView.setContentTitle("Search and book Diagnostics");
```